# Relaxed JSON parsing with Java

Tags: java, json

We have a situation where we have a large JSON file in which some of the values in the NV pairs have additional `"` characters, which is causing the Java parsing to fail.  I have been able to recreate the problem with the following sample JSON file.

```
{
  "sample-data": [
    {
      "name": "Peter Smith",
      "comment": "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
    },
    {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "comment": "This is so cool"
    },
    {
      "name": "Amy Brown",
      "comment": "He just exclaimed "OMG" when I approached him"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ronnie Arbuckle",
      "comment": "Peter O"Toole is a great bloke"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here JSON objects

```
{
  "name": "Amy Brown",
  "comment": "He just exclaimed "OMG" when I approached him"
}
```

and

```
{
  "name": "Ronnie Arbuckle",
  "comment": "Peter O"Toole is a great bloke"
}
```

are the ones that have the extra `"` issue.

---

**Q): Is there a way to perform "relaxed JSON parsing" with Java?**
We are okay with losing data from some of the objects in the process but we would like to salvage as much of the data as possible.

Comment: Can't you escape the quotes in the comments? "Peter O\"Toole is a great bloke"? And make the JSON well-formed and parseable?

Comment: @Heiko Jakubzik The JSON file is handed down to us. We don't create it from scratch.

Comment: Tell the people who handed the JSON file to you to fix their very buggy code.

Comment: Is the file formatted as shown? Because then you could just escape every double quote other than the first, second, thrid and last on every line...

Comment: @Siguza this is just a sample file that I created to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @Andreas that is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: In what type is it handed down? Can you take the string (or file) and do the escape with a replacement of all quotes between `:"` and `"}` (disregarding spaces)?

Comment: Your point about salvage is well taken - but if an apostrophe can be turned into a double-quote, what other surprises might you also encounter? (And I wonder if the producer could even consume what it produces?)

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to modify an original file's content slightly, I'd suggest to write a custom wrapper implementing java.io.Reader/java.io.InputStream and pass this reader/stream to your parsing library. This wrapper modifies the content on the fly. For example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class JsonFixer {
    private static final String CORRUPTED_JSON = "{\n" +
            "  \"name\": \"Amy Brown\",\n" +
            "  \"value\": 123,\n" +
            "  \"comment\": \"He just exclaimed \"OMG\" when I approached him\",\n" +
            "  \"comment\": \"He just exclaimed \\\"OMG\" when I approached him\",\n" +
            "  \"comment\": \"He just exclaimed \\\"OMG\\\" when I approached him\"\n" +
            "}";

    public static class FixingReader extends Reader {
        private final StringBuilder fixedLine = new StringBuilder();

        private final BufferedReader lineReader;

        private char[] currentLine;
        private int currentLineStart;
        private int currentLineLength;

        public FixingReader(final Reader reader) {
            if (reader instanceof BufferedReader) {
                lineReader = (BufferedReader) reader;
            } else {
                lineReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int read(final char[] cbuf, final int off, final int len) throws IOException {
            if (currentLineLength > 0) { // make the read of the rest of line
                final int left = currentLineLength - currentLineStart;
                final int read = Math.min(len, left);
                System.arraycopy(currentLine, currentLineStart, cbuf, off, read);
                currentLineStart += read;
                if (currentLineStart == currentLineLength) {
                    currentLineStart = 0;
                    currentLineLength = 0;
                }
                return read;
            }

            final String line = lineReader.readLine();
            if (line == null) { // EOF
                currentLineStart = 0;
                currentLineLength = 0;
                return -1;
            }

            int lineLength = line.length() + 1; // including \n on the end of the line to be restored
            currentLine = currentLine == null || currentLine.length < lineLength ?
                    new char[lineLength] :
                    currentLine; // reuse if we have enough space
            line.getChars(0, line.length(), currentLine, 0);
            currentLine[lineLength - 1] = '\n';
            fixedLine.setLength(0);

            // find the opening quotation mark
            int openQuoteIdx = -1;
            int qtCnt = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++) {
                final char c = currentLine[i];
                fixedLine.append(c); // write start of the line
                if (c != '"') {
                    continue;
                }
                qtCnt++;
                if (qtCnt == 3) {
                    openQuoteIdx = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // find the closing quotation mark
            int closeQuoteIdx = -1;
            for (int i = lineLength - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                if (currentLine[i] != '"') {
                    continue;
                }
                closeQuoteIdx = i;
                break;
            }
            if (openQuoteIdx > -1) { // if the line has quotation marks for the value
                // copy the rest of the string replacing the quotation mark
                boolean wasQuoted = false;
                for (int i = openQuoteIdx + 1; i < lineLength; i++) {
                    final char c = currentLine[i];
                    if (i >= closeQuoteIdx) {
                        fixedLine.append(c); // write end of the line
                        continue;
                    }
                    // can see a quotation mark
                    switch (c) {
                        case '\\':
                            wasQuoted = true;
                            break;
                        case '"':
                            if (!wasQuoted) {
                                fixedLine.append('\\');
                            }
                        default:
                            wasQuoted = false;
                    }
                    fixedLine.append(c);
                }
                if (fixedLine.length() > lineLength) {
                    currentLine = new char[fixedLine.length()];
                    fixedLine.getChars(0, fixedLine.length(), currentLine, 0);
                    lineLength = currentLine.length;
                }
            }

            currentLineStart = 0;
            currentLineLength = lineLength;

            // make the read
            final int read = Math.min(len, currentLineLength);
            System.arraycopy(currentLine, currentLineStart, cbuf, off, read);
            currentLineStart += read;
            if (currentLineStart == currentLineLength) {
                currentLineLength = 0;
            }
            return read;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            lineReader.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (BufferedReader fixedJson = new BufferedReader(new FixingReader(new StringReader(CORRUPTED_JSON)))) {
            fixedJson.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
}
```

prints the following output:

```
{
  "name": "Amy Brown",
  "value": 123,
  "comment": "He just exclaimed \"OMG\" when I approached him",
  "comment": "He just exclaimed \"OMG\" when I approached him",
  "comment": "He just exclaimed \"OMG\" when I approached him"
}
```

Such lightweight approach allows you to convert even large files, since it requires only one single line to be stored at once. This particular implementation works only for the case one line contains no more than one object property with its value. Otherwise, you have to modify the parsing properly.