# Convert Invalid Json to Valid Json

Tags: java, json, string

I have an invalid Json which has 2 double quoutes at value of "actualdeliverytime". I tried using JsonObject but it throws invalid Json error. I solved issue with this sdata.substring(0,sdata.length()-2)+"}"; approach. Is there a way to get valid json by using regex? I am newbie, sorry if it's very basic question.

```
{
    "actualdeliverydate": "20210505",
    "actualdeliverytime": "091812""
}
```

Comment: No, not really. One can only guess and there are plenty of cases where multiple things could have been meant. It should be fixed at the source where this JSON is coming from.

Comment: @Ivar That's true, but, but op asked for help with regex, so I still provided one that would work.

Comment: @IntoVoid It works _in this exact scenario_. But so does OP's original solution. What happens if you add another double quote in the middle of the number?

Comment: @Ivar It would be escaped in the original regex and therefore my pattern would just keep it. I also thought about this

Comment: @IntoVoid No it doesn't. If I change `"091812""` to `"091"812""`, the result I get with your solution is `"091"812"`

Comment: @Ivar But I would expect that a json writer (who made the original json code op provided) would always escape quotes. Therefore it would look something like this: "091\"812""

Comment: @Ivar I can also only make assumtions, since I've never seen a json writer end up making json code with two quotes at the end (producing invalid json code)

Comment: @IntoVoid So would I, but the invalid `"` at the end already proves that the writer produces invalid JSON.

Comment: @Ivar That is correct. Idk. Maybe it looses the escaped character at some point

Comment: @Ivar if I would respect that the regex would probably be eigher very very long or completly impossible for all scenarios. Op should trace back where the escape character is lost, or what went wrong in the first place

Comment: The project i'm working on makes a call to my java project from SAP and this invalid json comes from there. I take the Json from parameter and need to map it to an object. @IntoVoid

Comment: If you process small json data (as strings), you, of course, can use string manipulation methods like replace() etc, as suggested below. If you have to process large portions of data like really big files, you may look into this example (how to wrap a java.io.Reader) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66570095/relaxed-json-parsing-with-java/66603141#66603141 Your own wrapper can change reading data on the fly for your particular requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a workaround and not really something you should do in production. In addition, the JSON generation should be fixed at the source. Having said that (***only*** for the case you provided), replace consecutive double quote with a single double quote with string replace. Refer the implementation below:

```
package org.test;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class InvalidJSONTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        
        String invalid="{\r\n" + 
                "    \"actualdeliverydate\": \"20210505\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"actualdeliverytime\": \"091812\"\"\r\n" + 
                "}";
        
        String mayBeValid=invalid.replaceAll("\"\"", "\"");
        
        System.out.println(mayBeValid);
        
        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
        
        JsonNode node=mapper.readValue(mayBeValid.getBytes(), JsonNode.class);
        
        System.out.println(node.get("actualdeliverytime").asText());

    }//main closing

}//class closing
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
String valid_json = invalid_json.replaceAll("(\"(?:[^\"]|\\\\\")*\")\"", "$1");
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It needs to ignore escaped characters inside the strings

Comment: Wasn't downvoted by me but I still think that this will not work for all the scenarios. It is practically impossible to come up with a regex to handle all kinds of invalid json strings. And as for escaping the characters is concerned, existing libraries like Jackson, GSON already handles that

Comment: @ShyamBaitmangalkar that is true (I know about Gson), but it would probably also print an error when trying to parse a json with unescaped quotes like this. Also you are correct my solution won't work in all scenarios, but I guess it is the closest you can get using regex